# compare 2 text file lines and put # in new file lines present in old file

Tags: powershell

I am having 2 files with service details.

**File 1:**

```
Netlogon,OS,WARNING
#Opsware Agent,OS,WARNING
Server,OS,WARNING
VMware Tools,OS,WARNING
#Background Intelligent Transfer Service,OS,WARNING
#Background Tasks Infrastructure Service,OS,WARNING
#Base Filtering Engine,OS,WARNING
#Cb Defense WSC,OS,WARNING
#CDPUserSvc_214457e,OS,WARNING
```

**File 2:**

```
Netlogon,OS,WARNING
Opsware Agent,OS,WARNING
Server,OS,WARNING
VMware Tools,OS,WARNING
Background Tasks Infrastructure Service,OS,WARNING
Base Filtering Engine,OS,WARNING
Cb Defense WSC,OS,WARNING
CDPUserSvc_214457e,OS,WARNING
```

As you can see, In `File 1`, there are entries which are hashed out but not in `File 2` and also `File 2` is having 1 entry less than `File 1`.

I need to put `#` in front of each line in the new file (File 2) which is present in the old file (File 1). if any entry is not present in new file (File 2) we can ignore. So the output expected is

**File 2:**

```
Netlogon,OS,WARNING
#Opsware Agent,OS,WARNING
Server,OS,WARNING
VMware Tools,OS,WARNING
#Background Tasks Infrastructure Service,OS,WARNING
#Base Filtering Engine,OS,WARNING
#Cb Defense WSC,OS,WARNING
#CDPUserSvc_214457e,OS,WARNING
```

Please let me know how can I do that. I am able to fetch the hashed out entries from `File 1`
but not sure how to compare and modify

```
gc C:\Configs\Services.txt | % { if($_ -match "#") {write-host $_}}
```

Comment: take a look for this site https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-powershell-to-compare-two-files/

Comment: @KemalK.: I am aware of Compare-Object, but it will not help me here as it will only compare and give me the difference. I need to edit and put hash also in front of lines and save the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean to 'hash-out' any lines in file2 that are present as 'hashed-out' lines in file1 ?

Try

```
$file1 = Get-Content 'D:\Test\file1.txt'
$file2 = Get-Content 'D:\Test\file2.txt' | ForEach-Object {
    if ($file1.Contains("#$_")) { "#$_" }
    else { $_ }
}

$file2 | Set-Content -Path 'D:\Test\file3.txt'
```

Output in file3.txt:

```
Netlogon,OS,WARNING
#Opsware Agent,OS,WARNING
Server,OS,WARNING
VMware Tools,OS,WARNING
#Background Tasks Infrastructure Service,OS,WARNING
#Base Filtering Engine,OS,WARNING
#Cb Defense WSC,OS,WARNING
#CDPUserSvc_214457e,OS,WARNING
```

Answer (score 0):

Complementing Theo's [helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73235833/7571258), here is an approach using a [`Hashset`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=net-6.0) to quickly find lines from the 2nd file in the 1st file, without having to search through all lines linearly. This can give a noticable **performance improvement** if the actual input files consist of thousands of lines.

```sh
# Read the lines of the 1st file into a Hashset
[Collections.Generic.Hashset[string]] $file1Lines = Get-Content 'file1.txt'

# For each line of file 2
Get-Content 'file2.txt' | ForEach-Object {

    # Hashset overrides Contains() for much faster lookup, compared to array
    if( $file1Lines.Contains("#$_") ) { "#$_" } else { $_ }

    # Alternative for PS 7+: use ternary operator
    # $file1Lines.Contains("#$_") ? "#$_" : $_
} |
Set-Content 'Output.txt'
```