# Issue while comparing data from two text file using powershell

Tags: powershell

I am having 2 text files which are having service details

File 1 (New file)

```
Windows Remote Management (WS-Management),OS,WARNING
Windows Push Notifications System Service,OS,WARNING
#Background Intelligent Transfer Service,OS,WARNING
VMware Tools,OS,WARNING
#Windows Modules Installer,OS,WARNING
```

File 2 (

```
Windows Remote Management (WS-Management),OS,WARNING
Windows Push Notifications System Service,OS,WARNING
#Background Intelligent Transfer Service,OS,WARNING
VMware Tools,OS,WARNING
VMware Tools1,OS,WARNING
VMware Tools2,OS,WARNING
VMware Tools3,OS,WARNING
VMware Tools4,OS,WARNING
#Windows Modules Installer,OS,WARNING
```

Problem is when I am comparing the File 2 with File 1, there are some extra service which is present in File 2, but now they are not present in system. but which doing the comparison, my code is adding those extra services to the new file.

Please let me know what change I have to do in the code

```
$svr = $env:COMPUTERNAME

$newarr=@()
$arrwithouthash=@()
$final_arr=@()

$Rename_File = Copy-Item -Path "\\$svr\c$\Tivoli_Configs\Monitor_Services\Services_Mon.txt" -Destination "\\$svr\c$\Tivoli_Configs\Monitor_Services\Services_Mon_$((Get-Date).ToString("ddMMyyyy")).txt" -Force

$srvName = "K53CMA"
$servicePrior = Get-Service $srvName -ComputerName $svr

Stop-Service -Name $srvName -Force
sleep -Seconds 10
Start-Service -Name $srvName
sleep -Seconds 10
$serviceAfter = Get-Service $srvName

$file1 = gc "\\$svr\c$\Tivoli_Configs\Monitor_Services\Services_Mon_$((Get-Date).ToString("ddMMyyyy")).txt"
$file2 = Get-Content "\\$svr\c$\Tivoli_Configs\Monitor_Services\Services_Mon.txt" | ForEach-Object {
    if ($file1.Contains("#$_")) { "#$_" }
    else { $_ }
}

Clear-Content "\\$svr\c$\Tivoli_Configs\Monitor_Services\Services_Mon.txt" -Force
$file2 | Set-Content -Path "\\$svr\c$\Tivoli_Configs\Monitor_Services\Services_Mon.txt" -Force
```

Let me know if any other details needed

Original Post: [compare 2 text file lines and put # in new file lines present in old file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73235229/compare-2-text-file-lines-and-put-in-new-file-lines-present-in-old-file)

Comment: You forgot to tell us _why_ you're comparing the two files in the first place - what's the intended end result here?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen: Sorry for that. actually I am comparing servicemon file. So, every week I need to restart tivoli agent service, which will create a new servicemon file with new service details. now I have to take backup of the previous servicemon file, compare it with  new file and `#` out the services which are present in old servicemon file and update the new servicemon file
original post: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73235229/compare-2-text-file-lines-and-put-in-new-file-lines-present-in-old-file`

Comment: Try changing ```else { $_ }``` to ```elseif ($file1.Contains($_)) { $_ }``` - does that do what you're after?